# Embedding form partial in unconventional view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have rendered the regular scaffold form partial for a task model in my user show view. My thinking been so the user can post and see the post on the same page. I defined a task in the user show action like so

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@task = current_user.tasks.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @user }
end
end
```

And it does create the post but it does not show them. Any ideas as to why that is  ?

Show page

```
#_form
<%= form_for(@task) do |f| %>
 <% if @task.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
 <h2><%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this task from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
    <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
#_form

#index page
<% current_user.tasks.each do |task| %>
 <%= task.description %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you paste your `show` template?

Comment: r u getting any errors? show method does not have any post object? how are u getting post in view. Better to post the show template

Comment: added show page to original post

Answer (score 0):

This is weird because you find a `@user`, but you use `current_user` to create a new `task` instance for your form:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@task = current_user.tasks.new
```

I assume `current_user` already found the user model according to a cookie, session or token so you probably do not need `@user` in your `show` action.

With that aside, if you're concerned with the view not displaying the list of the `current_user`'s tasks, then you'll need to make sure the view has the proper markup, hence you should show us what your view currently looks like as well. Here's what I'm assuming you're trying to do:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @task = current_user.tasks.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: current_user }
    end
  end
end

class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.new params[:task]
    if @task.save
      # Send a new request to users#show
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      # No request will be sent to users#show and the template will just get
      # rendered with @task containing the same values from the initial request
      # with form input
      render 'users/show'
    end
  end
end

# app/views/users/show.html.erb

<ul><%= render current_user.tasks %></ul>

<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb

<li><%= task.name %></li>
```

Comment: Everything works fine when i post conventionally through the new view and action.

Comment: Just to be clear, your problem has nothing to do with creating new tasks? The problem is that the index page doesn't render the list of tasks from `current_user.tasks`? If so how are you sure that the task is being created when none of the tasks are being rendered?

Comment: The notice says it has been created and visiting the show page manually confirms it as well.

Comment: Just a thought. Is it possible that you're being redirected to the show page of the wrong "user"? You have `@user` being assigned in the `show` action, but you're accessing the list of tasks scoped to `current_user` in your view. Is `@user` and `current_user` guaranteed to be the same model? If so, why are you using both?

Comment: I see your point, a bit confused as too what to do there. I used the current user line to create tasks for the current user on the user show page. The line with the instance variable is not needed I guess but it is suppose to be there conventionally for the user show page.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "it is supposed to be there conventionally." You don't use the `@user` variable in the show page that you're showing us so it's not necessary at all. Unless there is some other part of the template you're not showing us that actually uses `@user`, you should get rid of that line and only reference a "user" with `current_user`.